# I want to control the voltage and current of a LTC3780 module using an Arduino

Tags: microcontroller, arduino, circuit-design, dc-dc-converter

[image]

Is it possible to adjust the voltage of [LTC3780](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/LTC3780.pdf) through this circuit?

I don't know much about circuits, but I designed it based on what I studied.

Please understand even if I’m not good at English.

[Link to the LTC3780 module](https://a.aliexpress.com/_ol6QiNz)

Comment: Can you edit the question to include the manufacturers part number or a link to the datasheet for the ``LTC3780 module``?

Comment: https://www.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/pdf/110626/LINER/LTC3780.html

Comment: Just found this amazing item on AliExpress. Check it out! ₩8,709  1%OFF | LTC3780EG LTC3780 DC-DC 5-32V to 1V-30V 10A Automatic Step Up Down Regulator Charging Module Power Supply Boost
https://a.aliexpress.com/_ol6QiNz

Comment: Nothing is amazing in electronics without a data sheet. Please provide the data sheet for the **module**

Answer (score 2):

There are a ton of Chinese modules that say they use the LTC3780. Without more information (specifically, a good schematic) it's hard to say exactly what could go wrong. The pricing suggests the LTC3780 itself may be counterfeit, as LTC (now AD) are generally very proud of their parts.

However it looks like you're replacing the *undervoltage protection adjust pot* with a sort of voltage source from the digital rheostat and 1kΩ resistor, which seems unlikely to give a satisfactory adjustment of output voltage, even if it works.

Typically voltage adjust of an IC regulator using a digital pot (or rheostat) requires mucking with the feedback circuit, which requires consideration that the voltages on the digital pot cannot exceed Vdd of the digital pot without potential damage.